# OAuth authentication with PhoneGap and RESTful WS

Tags: javascript, rest, spring-mvc, cordova, oauth-2.0

I am laying the ground-work for a Web App/PhoneGap app that will be using RESTful web services to share information and remember state, but I am struggling with the authentication pieces.

Basically, I would like to have two parts, one is a Web application and the other is a thick client app developed in PhoneGap, with all the client HTML and JS pieces local to the app and not served remotely.  Both the Web app and the PhoneGap app will use some RESTful WS'es to handle storage and state, and hosted as part of the Web app (same basic server code).  My intention is to use Spring Roo to write the Web app and REST pieces, so Spring Security is most likely going to be used there.  In both cases, I would like the authentication to be handled via OAuth2 through Google/Facebook/Twitter.  Here is where my lack of understanding is throwing me.

My understanding of OAuth is that you have to forward the user to the 3rd-party (Google/Facebook/Twitter), where they are authenticated and the access token is returned.  In fact, I have done this before using the traditional Web app model.  This access token is then used to do stuff against that service.  This makes sense to me from the traditional Web Application point of view, where I would simply push the user off to Google when they click the "Login with Google" button, but I can't seem to get past how to do this on a client app written in PhoneGap, and all of the examples I am finding look to want to host the PhoneGap application remotely, which I really don't want to do.  Furthermore, I am confused about some of the API key requirements, which seems to be based on a URL to forward the request back too.

The last piece I am struggling with is the REST calls.  I need to know who the user is when the REST call is made, but if the user is authenticating completely local to the PhoneGap application, and authentication is done by a 3rd party, how will I identify the user?  Do they pass  me the access token and I do something with that?

Admittedly, most of this confusion is due to my total lack of understand of OAuth and how it functions.